# Find remaining space in SQL anywhere database

Tags: database, sqlanywhere

How can I run a command to check to see how much space I have in total in my database and how much free space I have?

Answer (score 0):

```
CALL sa_disk_free_space( );
```

Reports information about space available for a dbspace, transaction log, transaction log mirror, and/or temporary file.

Result set:

- dbspace_name - This is the dbspace name, transaction log file, transaction log mirror file, or temporary file
- free_space - The number of free bytes on the volume.
- total_space - The    total amount of disk space available on the drive
  where the dbspace    resides

.